# Copy one file (randomly chosen) from every sub directory?

Tags: bash, unix, subdirectory

I have a nested directory structure, and at the lowest level are folders of .jpg files. I want to take one .jpg file from every sub-directory in this structure (there are thousands). How do I do this?

I can copy all the files, but not just a subset of them.

Comment: Can you share the output of `tree` command summarized ?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: It's too large to share, but basically the files I'm looking for are nested in /A/A/A/*.jpg, or /A/B/A/*jpg (plus every permutation of the alphabet)

Comment: Have you seen **`summarized`** ? And expected output.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First time poster, I hadn't seen that resource. Thank you for sharing! Will try to formulate my question a bit better next time!

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing one random file from each of many subdirectories:

```
find . -type d -links 2 -exec /bin/bash -c '
  dest=$1 ; shift
  for dir ; do
    cp "$( shuf -en1 "$dir"/*.jpg )" "$dest"
  done
' _ "$dest" {} +
```

- `find . -type d -links 2` searches for directories with no subdirectories
- Those directories get passed to a bash shell that uses `shuf` to pick one jpg from each directory and copies it to the destination folder

Comment: I've tried various permutations on this (maybe I'm adding my destination directory incorrectly? any guidance there?) but first got the error that there was a 'find: missing argument to `-exec'', so I added a terminating /;, but then I get that 'cp: cannot stat ‘./Subset/*.wav’: No such file or directory' ('Subset' is my intended destination directory name). I've also tried running this by hard coding the destination in rather than having it as an input, but no luck. The first line of code is finding all the subdirectories,  and the shuffle is working. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested) should work as long as your file and directory names don't include newlines:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -print |
    shuf |
    awk '{dir=$0; sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)} !seen[dir]++' |
    xargs -I {} cp {} /some/directory
```

Comment: @Linda There's no `-exec` in the script in my answer so I'm guessing you copy/pasted it incorrectly.